# How to Enable Desinger mode in Swagger Editor?

Tags: swagger, swagger-editor

I am new to swagger editor .In edit mode i have done documentaion of api very well.But the **Designer** mode is not get enabled in opera,chrome,Firefox . How can I enable this in my browser .? Here is a sample i have done in **editor mode** .

```
{
"swagger": "2.0",
"info": {
    "title": "Uber API",         
    "version": "1.0.0"
},
"host": "api.uber.com",
"schemes": [
    "https"
],
"basePath": "/v1",
"produces": [
    "application/json"
],
"paths": {
    "/products": {
        "get": {
            "summary": "Product Types",
            "description": " test",
            "parameters": [                    
                {
                    "name": "longitude",
                    "in": "query",
                    "description": "Longitude component of location.",
                    "required": true,
                    "type": "number",
                    "format": "double"
                }
            ],
            "tags": [
                "Products"
            ],
            "responses": {
                "200": {
                    "description": "An array of products"                       
                },
                "default": {
                    "description": "Unexpected error"                       
                }
            }
        }
    }
}}
```

How can do this with Desinger mode ? Please Help me .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you got your answer in the [github issue](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-editor/issues/276) you opened, but for anyone who may see the question here, the answer is simply that it is not implemented yet and as such not available.